# Nginx update on ubuntu fails

Tags: nginx

I am not nginx expert and having problems in configuring it.
Examples I found on web are slightly different so I wanted to update nginx 1.05 to 1.4.1 to see if it helps.

I have found instructions to install nginx from PPA as
   apt-get install python-software-properties
   add-apt-repository ppa:nginx/stable
   apt-get update
   apt-get install nginx

It seems as is it has installed but nginx -v is still telling me I have 1.0.5
What I missed?
Using ubuntu 11.10
Thanks

Comment: Side note: why are you still running ubuntu 11.10?

Answer (score 2):

NGINX maintains is own apt repository which means you don't need to use the PPA.
Firstly remove the added ppa:

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:nginx/stable
```

Then, if you're not running anything critical through nginx I would suggest running `apt-get remove --purge nginx` to completely remove nginx.

To use NGINX's repository add the following to `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/nginx.list':

```
deb http://nginx.org/packages/ubuntu/ oneiric nginx
deb-src http://nginx.org/packages/ubuntu/ oneiric nginx
```

Then run `apt-get update`. Then reinstall using `apt-get install nginx`.

Hope that works.

Comment: '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/nginx.list' instead i have '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/nginx-stable-trusty.list'   also i receive the following when doing apt-get update 'W: GPG error: http://nginx.org oneiric Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY ABF5BD827BD9BF62'

Comment: this wound up working for me http://serverfault.com/a/665984  $ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nginx/stable
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install nginx